# Is the tensor product of 2 free Abelian groups free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Ok, basically, I think that is true. Let's consider $A$, and $B$ are both free $\mathbb{Z}-$modules, i.e $A = \bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb{Z}$, and $B = \bigoplus_{j \in J} \mathbb{Z}$, so we'll have:

$$\begin{align}A \otimes B &= \left(\bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb{Z} \right) \otimes \left(\bigoplus_{j \in J} \mathbb{Z} \right) \\
&= \bigoplus_{(i, j) \in I \times J} \left( \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z} \right) \\
&= \bigoplus_{(i, j) \in I \times J} \mathbb{Z}  \end{align}$$

So $A \otimes B$ is also free. Does my proof look correct?

---

My second question is, I wonder if I can prove it directly, i.e, say $A$ is free with base $\left\{ \alpha_i \right\}_{i \in I}$, and $B$ is free with base $\left\{ \beta_j \right\}_{j \in J}$, I'll try to prove that $A \otimes B$ is also free with base $\left\{ \alpha_i \otimes \beta_j \right\}_{i \in I, j \in J}$.

I can prove that, the set $\left\{ \alpha_i \otimes \beta_j \right\}_{i \in I, j \in J}$ does indeed, generate $A \otimes B$, but how can I prove that they are linearly independent? The hardest part I'm facing is that I don't know what $0 \in A \otimes B$'s representations are, i.e under what conditions will $\sum\limits_{\text{finite}} a_i \otimes b_i$ equal to $0$. Is there some way to do it?

Thank you guys very much,

And have a good day,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part looks fine, assuming you've shown that $\oplus$ distributes over $\otimes$ in the way you have written. For the second approach, here is a useful function: with your notation, define a map $A \times B \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ by fixing indices $i_0, j_0$ and writing each $(a,b)$ as $a =  \sum_i n_i \alpha_i$ and $b = \sum_j m_j \beta_j$. Since the integers appearing in the sum are unique, we can define $\phi(a,b) = n_{i_0}m_{j_0}$. This map is then $\mathbb{Z}$-multilinear and so gives a map $A \otimes B \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ that does nice things for you.